# How do I tell if a disk image (.sparseimage) is encrypted?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to confirm that an image is encrypted? When I choose "Get info" in Finder, it reveals nothing, and when I use Disk utility I also can't seem to see the information.

I know I could try mount it on another machine and see if I need to use a password, but I'm looking for a clean way to get OSX to tell me that it's encrypted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a few ways to check. The last one only works in Lion. The third one is probably the easiest if you're comfortable using Terminal.

**Lock All Keychains**

A quick way to check is to open Keychain Access (found in /Applications/Utilities/), choose File > Lock All Keychains, then try to mount the disk image.

If it's encrypted, you should get a message like

> diskimages-helper wants to use the "login" keychain

and be prompted for the keychain password (same as your OS X login password). If it's not encrypted, it will simply mount.

**Search login Keychain**

Instead of locking all keychains, you could instead search for your disk image in the login keychain: Select the login keychain, then type the name of the .sparseimage file in the search field.

However, if the .sparseimage name has been changed since it was created, it won't show up in the login keychain with the new name.

If you don't find your disk image you can try the Lock All Keychains method above or the Terminal method below to be certain.

**Terminal Command**

You can enter the following command to check if the disk image is encrypted:

```
hdiutil imageinfo /path/to/image | grep Encryption
```

Replace the `/path/to/image` with the path to the disk image. If the disk image is encrypted, the command will return something like:

```
     Encryption: AES-128
```

If it's not encrypted, it won't show anything at all.

**Use Disk Utility in Lion**

New in Lion, Disk Utility now shows if a disk image is encrypted.

1. Unmount the disk image if it's mounted.
2. Open Disk Utility and drag the .sparseimage file to the device list on the left side of the Disk Utility window.
3. Select the .sparseimage in the device list and look at the information area at the bottom of the window. If the disk is encrypted, then that will be indicated under "Disk Write Status".

Answer (score 15):

from the command line you can use '`hdiutil isencrypted {image-name}`'.

```
bash-3.2$ hdiutil isencrypted unencrypted.sparseimage
encrypted: NO
bash-3.2$ hdiutil isencrypted encrypted.sparseimage
encrypted: YES
blocksize: 512
uuid: FC3C26ED-3056-4F98-8248-DD2F16B39357
private-key-count: 0
passphrase-count: 1
max-key-count: 1
version: 2
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: :-) You beat me by a few seconds here...

Comment:  Best answer if you only want to know encrypted or not? Whereas the [answer of @joelseph](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/26797/11510) is best if you want to know the details of the encryption scheme, but in order to get that answer you are first need to provide the password for decryption.

Answer (score 3):

`hdiutil isencrypted <image-name>` will do the trick.

From the hdiutil(1) man page :

> isencrypted image: print a line indicating whether image is encrypted.  If it is, additional details are printed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with Mavericks. It was surprisingly hard to tell if my disk image was truly encrypted, or if it simply had the same name as an image that was previously encrypted.

As long as it had been mounted one time, Disk Utility did not show it as encrypted. Locking Keychain access did not help, it is as though OS X was caching encryption keys.

I had to unmount the image, remove all references in Keychain Access, then try to mount it. Then I got asked for a password.

Once it's in a state where Mavericks requests a password, Disk Utility DID show the image file (not mounted image) as "Not mounted, encrypted".

If you dismount first, and are willing to use terminal, then as noted by Patrix and Stephen, hdiutil isencrypted {image-name} works with Mavericks.